Does compressing air increase the average speed of the air molecules?
If you have a cubic foot of air and compress it, will the speed of the molecules stay the same or increase?
I know that the air will heat up the surrounding objects because the molecules are in a more confined space when at high pressure, making them bounce off of each other and the object more, heating it up.
However, does this mean that the speed of the air molecules themselves increases? If so, why?

Whether the compression is accomplished slowly enough so that additional energy is essentially entirely dissipated to the surroundings matters.  In essence there is not enough information in the problem about the surroundings and timing to make a good answer yet.

If you model the gas as an ideal gas, it depends on how you compress the gas. For the ideal gas, the average speed of the molecules is determined by the gas's temperature. When you compress the gas, you can do so in a way that increases, decreases, or doesn't change the temperature of the gas. It depends on how the system is interacting with the environment as well as what state the environment is in.

Interesting. Could you provide an example for when the gas temp would decrease with compression? Not denying that it happens, but it just seems counterintuitive.

@Wyatt During compression you just need to have the gas in thermal contact with something that can move heat out of your system at a fast enough rate.

Think of an individual particle bouncing (elastically) off a wall. If the wall is stationary, the particle will bounce back with the same speed as it collided with. If the wall is moving toward it, it will bounce back with a higher speed.
It's easy to see this if you think of what happens in the frame of the moving wall, since in that frame, the particle bounces back with its incident speed.

Generally, this would tend to increase the average speed of the air molecules- you have done work on the gas and this work has to go somewhere- most likely increasing the average kinetic energy of the gas molecules considering all methods for compressing a gas. It is possible to compress the gas extremely slowly as it exchanges heat with it's surroundings so the average kinetic energy of the gas molecules does not change- but compared with all the ways of compressing the gas that does increase the internal energy you are most likely going to increase the average speed of the gas molecules.
